# Google Play Games connection method is needed in all Activity

Tags: android, google-play-games, leaderboard, android-studio-2.3

In my app i'm connecting **Google Play Games** in one Activity, and I'm submitting score to **Leaderboard** in another activity but it is not submitting score, in this activity i'm submitting score only not written any connection method.

Whether Google Play Games Connection method is needed in all activity.

Help me to solve this is Issue.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, network connection is required in submitting score in [Leaderboards](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/leaderboards).

You may, however, save game data locally on the device if the player's device is not connected to a network by calling [`commitAndClose()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/snapshot/Snapshots#commitAndClose(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.Snapshot,%20com.google.android.gms.games.snapshot.SnapshotMetadataChange)). Then, upon device re-connection, Google Play games services syncs the locally cached saved game changes to Google's servers. See [Writing Saved Games](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames#writing_saved_games) for more information.

And, on [offline support](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames#offline_support),

> Your game can still read and write to a saved game when the player's device is offline, but will not be able to sync with Google Play games services until network connectivity is established. Once reconnected, Google Play games services asynchronously updates the saved game data on Google's servers.

Comment: sir for me google play games is connected in one activity , i want to submit score to leaderboard in another activity but i don't know which method is i need to write for submit score and connection in another activity.